# Генераторы и Итераторы простым языком

Tags: php

Может кто нибудь объяснить простым языком что такое генераторы и итераторы, например в php и чем отличается return от yield?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return` возвращает значение и прекращает работу функции.

`yield` возвращает значение и переходит к началу цикла, работает дальше до тех пор, пока все значения не закончатся или пока приниматель значений не скажет "хватит!"

Comment: "переходит к началу функции" - ээ, yield в php настолько радикально отличается от других языков с yield?

Comment: @andreymal в других не переходит?

Comment: Ну как минимум в питоне и js точно не переходит

Comment: не переходит в начало в php а продолжает выполнение. надо зациклить для повторения

Comment: @andreymal Ну да, коряво выразился. Не в начало функции, а цикл, из которого yield, дальше выполняется.

Comment: И всё равно не знаю как в php, но как минимум в питоне функция с yield совершенно не обязана иметь цикл)

Comment: @andreymal а откуда тогда значения генерируются?

Comment: Значения совершенно не обязаны генерироваться)) https://jsfiddle.net/8fq2L3cw/

Comment: @andreymal в php так же. Просто проще объяснить, если говорить про цикл. Что такое цикл - это последовательное использование next и т.д. Только next  никто почти не пользуется (если говорить про новичков), а циклами - да.

Answer (score 2):

Дополню.

Итератор - по простому это объект (или другие контрукции), которые можно прогонять в цикле. Точнее Итератор - это интерфейс для этого, а вот то что можно прогнать в цикле  - это итерируемый объект.

Массив - пример итерируемой структуры языка. Коллекция - это итерируемый объект.

Генератор - это тоже итератор, но только с другой структурой.  Он позволяет остановиться на том моменте, где был прошлый цикл. Лучше почитать документацию, как это работает.

В целом генератор итератором. А итератор (итерируемый объект, только объект не смысле ООП, а в смысле простого указания) - это все, что можно использовать в цикле.